# CodeIgniter 4 Only default route / is accessible, no other route is working if i define in my Routes.php. I am using ubuntu

Tags: php, codeigniter, routes, codeigniter-4

My .htaccess file inside app/.htaccess and project directory is here. Both are same.
i am using the same .htaccess file which is present inside public directory in both app and project directoyr

Routes.php is here

```
<?php 
namespace Config;

// Create a new instance of our RouteCollection class.
$routes = Services::routes();

// Load the system's routing file first, so that the app and ENVIRONMENT
// can override as needed.
if (file_exists(SYSTEMPATH . 'Config/Routes.php'))
{
    require SYSTEMPATH . 'Config/Routes.php';
}

/**
 * --------------------------------------------------------------------
 * Router Setup
 * --------------------------------------------------------------------
 */
$routes->setDefaultNamespace('App\Controllers');
$routes->setDefaultController('Home');
$routes->setDefaultMethod('index');
$routes->setTranslateURIDashes(false);
$routes->set404Override();
$routes->setAutoRoute(true);

/**
 * --------------------------------------------------------------------
 * Route Definitions
 * --------------------------------------------------------------------
 */

// We get a performance increase by specifying the default
// route since we don't have to scan directories.
$routes->get('/test', 'Home::test');
$routes->get('/test', 'Home::test');
/**
 * --------------------------------------------------------------------
 * Additional Routing
 * --------------------------------------------------------------------
 *
 * There will often be times that you need additional routing and you
 * need it to be able to override any defaults in this file. Environment
 * based routes is one such time. require() additional route files here
 * to make that happen.
 *
 * You will have access to the $routes object within that file without
 * needing to reload it.
 */
if (file_exists(APPPATH . 'Config/' . ENVIRONMENT . '/Routes.php'))
{
    require APPPATH . 'Config/' . ENVIRONMENT . '/Routes.php';
}
```

On / it working fine. But on /test it give me error.

The requested URL was not found on this server. how can i fix this issue. My index.php is working fine.

Comment: `it give me error` ...what is the error?

Comment: You only need to specify the route once ( you have it twice) and is there a test method in your home controller?

Comment: yes i define function in Home conroller with name test, also it doesn't make any effect by defining one route.

Comment: The error is that    Not Found
The requested URL was not found on this server.

Apache/2.4.38 (Debian) Server at 217.146.76.1 Port 80

Comment: <?php namespace App\Controllers;

class Home extends BaseController
{
 public function index()
 {
  echo "test";
 }
 public function test()
 {
  echo "This is test function";
 }

 //--------------------------------------------------------------------

}

Answer (score 2):

Try this

$routes->get('/test', 'App\Controllers\Home::test');

But for this to work, you need to have a Controller named Home inside Controllers folder and also a method named test inside the controller.

Comment: <?php namespace App\Controllers;

class Home extends BaseController
{
 public function index()
 {
  echo "test";
 }
 public function test()
 {
  echo "This is test function";
 }

 //--------------------------------------------------------------------

} still the same issue after changing routes.php

Answer (score 0):

in your Home controller does it method that have a

```
return view('test');
```

or

```
echo view('test');
```

or you want to access folder test and viewed them?
if so, check is there a folder name test inside View also a test.php inside folder test?
if you done checking that and all exist then you can write the code like this

```
return view('/test/test');
```

or

```
echo view('/test/test');
```

since you don't show us a complete code, this is what i guess.
hope this will solve the problem.